# Tirar uma amostra sem repetição levando em consideração 2 variáveis no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Possuo duas bases. Uma com as linhas que gostaria de tirar a amostra e a outra com o tamanho da amostra com as data. A primeira que é a base de dados de fato que preciso fazer a amostra, está exemplificada abaixo chamada "bons":

```
CNPJ    data
333333  201601
333333  201612
111111  201612
111111  201610
111111  201607
111111  201611
22222   201605
22222   201606
22222   201610
22222   201509
99999   201605
99999   201612
99999   201611
99999   201601
```

A segunda base está abaixo chamada "tamamostra", ela possui apenas o tamanho da amostra que necessito para cada data, sendo que essa amostra deve ser feita com CNPJs que não se repetem:

```
data    201509  201510  201512  201601  201602  201603  201604  201605  201606  201607  201610  201611  201612  Total
ruins   1          1       1       6       4       3       2       4       3       5       5       4       6       45
bons    3          3       3       14      10      7       5       10      7       12      12      10      14      105
Total   4          4       4       20      14      10      7       14     10    17         17      14      20      155
```

Preciso fazer uma amostra de tamanho "bons" para cada data sem repetir o mesmo CNPJ. Ou seja, para 201509 preciso de uma amostra de tamanho 3 com 3 CNPJs diferentes sendo que esses CNPJs não podem se repetir para as outras datas, para 201601 preciso de uma amostra de tamanho 14 com CNPJs que não se repetem na data anterior e assim sucessivamente, tendo, no final, uma amostra total de tamanho 105 com CNPJs únicos. Vale destacar que existem alguns CNPJs que não possuem algumas datas.

Tentei utilizar o for com o sample para fazer essa amostra, porém, como não especifiquei que o CNPJ não podia se repetir, alguns CNPJs saíram repetidos:

```
for(i in 2:14){
bons1[i]<-subset(bons,data==tamamostra[1,i])[sample(nrow(subset(bons,data==tamamostra[1,i])), tamamostra[3,i]), ]
}
```

Como fazer isso no R? Acredito que o pacote dplyr deve ter alguma solução.

Comment: Pode não haver uma tal amostra. Por exemplo, se os 4 CNPJs de 201510 forem os mesmos de 201512, não tem como escolher 3 de um e 3 do outro sem haver algo em comum.

Comment: Não ficou claro a sua pergunta. Você precisa de uma amostra de tamanho n com n CNPJs, para as m datas, ok, mas qual a relação entre os dois conjuntos de dados?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. A base é grande e é possível fazer.

Comment: @T.Veiga, ainda não ficou claro qual a relação da base 1 com a base 2, veja para seu exemplo, data = 201509, vc precisa de 3 amostra, ou seja 3 CNPJs, essa amostra seria retiradas da base 1 (bons), correto? Cada CNPJ seria aleatório ou teria alguma relação com a coluna data? Essa saída os CNPJs seriam mesclados ou separados?
A saída possível para esse exemplo poderia ser: "111111”, “22222”, “333333” ou 11111122222333333?

Answer (score 2):

Como seus dados de exemplo não possuem tamanho suficiente para uma amostragem sem repetição, estou gerando outros, mais simples, só para demonstração:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  CNPJ = rep(1:20, each = 3),
  data = 2015:2017
)

tam <- data.frame(
  data = 2015:2017,
  bons = 1:3
)
```

A tabela com o tamanho das amostras precisa estar em formato "longo". No caso dos seus dados, você pode convertê-los da seguinte maneira:

```
tamamostra <- read.table(text = c('
  data    201509  201510  201512  201601  201602  201603  201604  201605  201606  201607  201610  201611  201612  Total
  ruins   1          1       1       6       4       3       2       4       3       5       5       4       6       45
  bons    3          3       3       14      10      7       5       10      7       12      12      10      14      105
  Total   4          4       4       20      14      10      7       14     10    17         17      14      20      155')
)
tam <- as.data.frame(t(tamamostra[,-c(1,ncol(tamamostra))]))
names(tam) <- tamamostra[[1]]
```

## Usando loop com subset

A ideia aqui é sequencialmente amostrar CNPJs por datas e cortar os sorteados da tabela de dados:

```
#data.frame para receber as amostras
amostra <- data.frame(
  CNPJ = NA,
  data = rep(tam$data, tam$bons)
)

# cópia dos dados, para preservar o original
dados -> dados.temp

for (data in tam$data) {
  samp.cnpj <- sample(dados.temp[dados.temp$data == data, 'CNPJ'], size = tam[tam$data == data, 'bons'])
  samp.cnpj -> amostra[amostra$data == data, 'CNPJ']
  dados.temp <- dados.temp[!dados.temp$CNPJ %in% samp.cnpj,]
}; rm(dados.temp, samp.cnpj)

> amostra
  CNPJ data
1    6 2015
2   18 2016
3    8 2016
4    7 2017
5   15 2017
6   19 2017
```

## Sorteando primeiro uma data para cada CNPJ

Aqui a ideia é primeiro sortear uma data para cada CNPJ (de modo que não haja repetição) para depois amostrar os CNPJs por data, usando para isso o pacote `data.table`. Esta solução é potencialmente mais rápida para um conjunto de dados muito grande, mas podem não restar CNPJs suficientes para fazer a amostragem.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dados)
amostra <- dados[, .(data = sample(data, 1)), by = CNPJ][tam, on = 'data'][, sample(CNPJ, bons), by = data]
names(amostra)[2] <- 'CNPJ'

> amostra
   data CNPJ
1: 2015    9
2: 2016    1
3: 2016   16
4: 2017    2
5: 2017    8
6: 2017    7
```

(Agradecimento ao @juan-antonio-roldán-díaz pela sugestão desta ideia)

Comment: @t-veiga Eu não uso `dplyr`, mas se quiser usar a segunda proposta com ele, esta resposta no SO em inglês pode ajudá-lo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669338/9817508